# Leaflet error: Object function has no method 'createIcon' when creating custom icon markers in LayerGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am creating markers from an XML stream, and setting custom icons in them.  I want to have my markers in group layers so that I can support turning all markers of a certain type off.  I receive the following error when I add a marker to my map (using GroupLayer) with a custom Icon:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function
>   (){this.initialize&&this.initialize.apply(this,arguments)} has no
>   method 'createIcon'

#### Example icon

```
 var ATVIcon = L.Icon.extend({
     iconUrl: './markers/atv.png',
     shadowUrl: '',
     iconSize: new L.Point(27, 17),
     shadowSize: new L.Point(0, 0),
     iconAnchor: new L.Point(22, 22),
     popupAnchor: new L.Point(-3, -76)
 });
```

#### Example Layer

```
var layerATV = new L.LayerGroup();
```

Adding marker to map or LayerGroup

```
var thisMarker = new L.Marker(markerLocation, {title: $(this).attr('name')});
    targetLayerGroup.addLayer(thisMarker);
    thisMarker.setIcon(targetIcon);
```

I have tried adding group layers to map first, then markers to group layers:

1. Icon vars are instanced
2. GroupLayer vars are instanced
3. GroupLayers are added to Map
4. Marker is created with Icon option
5. Marker is added to GroupLayer

And I have tried adding markers to group layers first and then adding group layers to map:

1. Icon vars are instanced
2. GroupLayer vars are instanced
3. Marker is created with Icon option
4. Marker is added to GroupLayer
5. GroupLayers are added to Map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When referencing the icons, you need to have parenthesis as you are newing them up rather than just assigning to a variable...

```
case 'church':
    targetLayerGroup = layerChurch;
    targetIcon = new ChurchIcon();
    break;
```

As opposed to:

```
case 'church':
    targetLayerGroup = layerChurch;
    targetIcon = ChurchIcon;
    break;
```